# Getting awk return value with Java

Tags: java, linux, shell, unix, terminal

I am writing a simple shell command for our Java application. I have no experience in Linux shell and need a simple command. What i try to do is get user's active window's process name. From another question I found a script as follows:

```
ps -e | grep $(xdotool getwindowpid $(xdotool getwindowfocus)) | grep -v grep | awk '{print $4}'
```

Source:https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38867/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-the-active-window-process-title-in-gnome

I am able to test and print the result but. Can't get the value from Java side. However if I run a simple script like

```
echo asdasd
```

I can get the "asdasd" String just fine. As i understand Java can only get echo commands.

At java side I use this method:
    private String executeCommand(String command) {

```
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = 
                        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                    String line = "";           
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return output.toString();

}
```

Source: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/

------SOLVED------

Solved thanks to smasseman's answer, however I changed the command String with  th following String array,

```
String[] args = {"/bin/sh","-c",command };
```

"command" is the script itself not the filepath as it gave errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use pipes when you execute it from java. The trick is to write your linux commands and pipes into a script and execute that script from java.
Create this script (lets call the script activewin.sh):

`#!/bin/bash
ps -e | grep $(xdotool getwindowpid $(xdotool getwindowfocus)) | grep -v grep | awk '{print $4}'`

Make is executable `chmod +x activewin.sh`
Then you can execute the script in java `p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./activewin.sh");`

You could of course write the script file from java, execute it and then remove it if you want you application to be more "stand alone".

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [Apache Comons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/) for this.